# Draggabilly and Packery highlight drop area

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, packery

My question relates to a excellent javascript library called [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) which I am using to create a masonry style layout. I am also using a sister script called [draggabilly](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html) to allow the user to drag and drop (reorder) the items in the page. Currently I am doing something fairly similar to conventional usage: 
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/CKbkw

When you drag an item the interface leaves a space large enough for the element to be dropped. I wanted to place a div there temporarily to indicate that this is where the element will be dropped. All I really need is a way to get the x, y co-ordinates for where the dragged element will come to rest once released but I can't seem to figure out how to get that information.

and I am using a dragMove listener which is where I expect to display my div and provide it with the correct co-ordinates:

```
draggie.on( 'dragMove', function(draggieInstance, event, pointer) {
    //code to display and position ghost div
});
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.